# Is there an elegant way to convert a Map<P, Optional<Q>> to a sparse Map<P, Q>?

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

Is there an elegant way to convert a `Map<P, Optional<Q>>` to a sparse `Map<P, Q>` ?

This should work, but it's a bit meh:

```
Map<P,Optional<Q>> map = ...;
Map<P,Q> map2 = map.entrySet()
                  .stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e->e.getValue().get()));
```

Comment: Maybe: `map.forEach((key, optional) -> optional.ifPresent(value -> map2.put(key, value)));` but `map2` has to be initialized first: `Map<P, Q> map2 = new HashMap<>(); `

Answer (score 11):

I would say your way almost already is the most elegant way, I'd only do some slight cosmetic changes and replace `e -> e.getKey()` in your collector with `Entry::getKey`. This is only a small change, but communicates your *intent* better then the other lambda.

```
Map<P, Optional<Q>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<P, Q> sparseMap = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().get()));
```

**Why aren't the other solutions better / more elegant?**

Because they aren't more concise, and they again fall into the trap of not declaring *what* you want to do, but *how*, which is common in procedural styles, but not so much in functional ones.

If you look at the above code, it is pretty much self-explanatory and has a nice flow to it. You first have a non-sparse map with `Optional`s, then declare the sparse map without `Optional`s and then describe the transformation of the former map into the latter. This has also no side-effects. The sparse map is assigned only when the collector is actually finished.

If you look at other solutions, those *invert* the logic flow and use the procedural way of thinking:

```
Map<P, Optional<Q>> map = [....];
Map<P, Q> sparseMap = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((key, opt) -> opt.ifPresent(value -> sparseMap.put(key, value)));
```

This is only marginally shorter then:

```
Map<P, Optional<Q>> map = [....];
Map<P, Q> sparseMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Entry<P, Optional<Q>> e : map.entrySet()) e.getValue().ifPresent(value -> sparseMap.put(key, value))
```

You save a few chars due to type inference, but in the end, if you format them reasonably, both `foreach` solutions need 4 LOC, so they aren't shorter then the functional one. They aren't clearer, either. On the *contrary*, they rely on causing *side-effects* in the other map. Which means during computation, you get a partially constructed sparse map assigned to your variable. With the functional solution, the map is only assigned when it is properly constructed. This is only a small nitpick, and likely not going to cause issues in this case, but is something to keep in mind for other situations where it might become relevant (e.g. when concurrency is involved), especially when the other map isn't a local variable but a field -- or worse, passed in from somewhere else.

Furthermore, the functional approach scales better - switching to a parallel stream if you have lots of data is trivial, converting the `foreach`-approach to parallel requires rewriting to the functional `filter`/`collect` approach anyways. This isn't relevant for such lightweight operations (in fact, do not do it here, its likely slower), but in other situations that might be a desirable characteristic.

In my opinion, using the functional `filter`/`collect` approach is preferable to using the procedural `foreach`, because you train yourself to use good habits. But keep in mind that "elegance" is often in the eye of the beholder. To me, the more "elegant" way is the proper functional way which has no side effects. YMMV.

Comment: While the ability to parallelize the stream is nice in theory, I'd very much like to see the map for which a parallel stream performs this task more efficiently than a sequential one (or just iterating over the map directly). In general, parallel streams are useful when the entries must go through some slow nontrivial processing that can be usefully shared among multiple threads. Just extracting a value from an Optional, however, is such a lightweight operation that the overhead of parallelizing it is likely to exceed the cost of the operation itself by a considerable margin.

Comment: Why not transform the Entry<P, Optional<Q>> into  Entry<P, Q> with a map before collecting into a map?

Comment: `map.forEach` “is only marginally shorter” than the `for` loop, because you’re using the raw type `Entry`. A correct solution would have to use `Entry<P, Optional<Q>>`, so the difference in code size depends on the actual `P` and `Q`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Absolutely, its irrelevant in this case. That is why I pointed out developing good habits. because when you get into the situation where you need it, you do not need different code then the one you are already writing.

Comment: @Holger true, will change that a bit

Answer (score 10):

How about this:

```
Map<P, Q> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((key, opt) -> opt.ifPresent(value -> map2.put(key, value)));
```

Answer (score 6):

It's simpler when you create a new map and add values by iterating over the original map:

```
Map<P, Q> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((p, q) -> map2.compute(p, (k, v) -> q.orElse(null)));
```

All original entries for which `value.isPresent()` would return `false` are skipped (not included in `result`): `Map.compute` removes/ignores the key's mapping when `remappingFunction` yields `null`.

---

Here's an example to clarify how nulls are dealt with:

```
Map<String, Optional<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("one", Optional.of(1));
map.put("two", Optional.of(2));
map.put("three", Optional.empty());
map.put("four", Optional.of(4));
map.put("five", Optional.empty());

Map<String, Integer> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map.forEach((p, q) -> map2.compute(p, (k, v) -> q.orElse(null)));

System.out.println(map2);
```

The output is `{four=4, one=1, two=2}` (when `map2.compute` gets `null` from `q.orElse`, `p` is not added to `map2`)

Comment: @nullpointer I see that particular aspect attracts attantion. Please read my last sentence in this post :-)

Comment: @ernest_k Still `null` looks a bit nasty. I would avoid it if possible.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I'm probably not explaining correctly. It's not inserting nulls. I'll add an example.

Comment: It's short but I don't find it very readable. If I saw this in a larger codebase it wouldn't be immediately obvious what it does.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks for the opinion. Readability is both relative and (sometimes) secondary.

Comment: @ernest_k: Sometimes, yes. However, [ZhekaKozlov's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54748736) seems noticeably more readable to me, and I'd be surprised if it wasn't also more efficient.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen That's one of the best things about SO ;-) - a question gets answers of many kinds, some better than others in one one or many ways. That's why we sometimes can't resist upvoting even answers competing against our own. That's how we learn or just get to discover other perspectives. That's how we learn here: seeing examples of both right and wrong (with the help of arguments for and against anything). It's not a competition, after all...

Comment: "Map.compute removes/ignores the key's mapping when remappingFunction yields null." Is that really so? The JavaDoc does not seem to give this guarantee: "Attempts to compute a mapping for the specified key and its current mapped value (or null if there is no current mapping)." Maybe you are confusing `compute` with `computeIfAbsent`, which says: "If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless null."? Are you sure all Map implementations do as you claim?

Comment: @Polygnome You misunderstood both my comment and the javadocs. The docs say if you call `map.compute(nonExistentKey, biFunction)` and `biFunction.apply(nonExistentKey, null) == null`, then `nonExistentKey` won't be added to `map`. If you called `compute(existingKey, biFunction)` and `biFunction` returns null, then `existingKey` is removed from `map`. Would be nice if you took a minute to run the code in the post (and add `map2.compute("six", (k, v) -> null);` after the `forEach`). Result will be the same. This is the contract of `Map`, it has no exceptions or ifs for implementations.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen well yes, ZhekaKozlov’s solution has the advantage of not performing a hash operation for the empty optionals. This can result in higher performance if there’s a significant number of empty optionals.

Answer (score 3):

I would stick with what you have. It directly expresses the intent and it leverages streaming, a quality the other answers lack. Sometimes `Stream`s are verbose, nothing you can do.

```
Map<P,Q> map2 = map.entrySet()
                  .stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().isPresent())
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue().get()));
```